# How to develop a GPS Navigation app for a Resort Area in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, geolocation

Hi Programming Experts.

I'm a newbie learner of Android. I've tried developing some applications which uses SQLite database, HTTP and all.

Now I'm going to develop an app which helps me to navigate through a Resort area, which is installed on a Tablet or Phone. I've to know where I'm now(current location), the landmarks nearby(inside the resort). When I touch on a landmark marker, a screen should appear which shows the latest info about the landmark and its services. A private server is set to store updated info and it sends the info to the client when requested. I've to navigate through the outside area. i.e, parking area, way to the landmarks etc. No navigation required inside the building for now.

Guys, please help me out, since I'm not aware of GPS implementation in Android.

Advanced Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, bud?

Comment: i went through https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html. But I'm not getting any idea where to start. Getting the current location is the first step?

Comment: if you arent understanding the tutorial then you should check out the source and debug to see what exactly happens mate. Heres the link to the source code in the tutorial. http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/LocationUpdates.zip

Comment: Not a problem bud, Please do come back and ask questions :)